# How to use $geoIntersects in MongoDB properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, mongodb-query

I wann to use $geoIntersects for checking whether a point is in a polygon.

I have saved UK regions from [here](https://github.com/glynnbird/ukcountiesgeojson) in my mongo database. 
 I saved all geoJSON entity  with mongoose-geojson-schema module.

Here is defined schema in mongoose

```
var geozoneSchema = mongoose.model('Geozone', {
    geoFeature:  GeoJSON.Feature,
    average:    {type: Number, default: null},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I wrote this query, but it didn't work.

```
Geozone.findOne({
    "geometry.coordinates": {
        "$geoIntersects": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": fakeUser.loc
            }
        }
    }
}, function(err, foundGeozone) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('found geozone: ', foundGeozone);
    if (foundGeozone) {
        console.log('found geozone! Good! Save User.');
    }
});
```

In fakeUser.loc is stored this point

```
 user.loc = [-3.2, 54.5]; //real loc
```

So I am sure that point really inside particular stored region, but variable foundGeozone is null.

Maybe, my query is wrong or something else. Could you help me?

Comment: So is the "point" actually on a "line" that makes up the polygon? Or did you mean `$geoWithin`? Sample data, expected outcome. That is what makes a clear question.

Comment: @NeilLunn Point not on a polygon border now, but I think it's possible in the future. Is there significant different what I use, geoIntersect or geoWithin? I think geoIntersect should work properly, or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: It either "intersects" or it does not. It's a `true|false` evaluation. "intersects" and "within" are two different things. Test for one or both as required.

Comment: @NeilLunn $geoWithin doesn't work.

Comment: Not really informative considering the lack of data and expected result in your question. Give people something to work with if you want a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

From the data schema in https://github.com/glynnbird/ukcountiesgeojson, your location field to search should be "`geometry`", not "`geometry.coordinates`":

```
Geozone.findOne({
    "geometry": {
        "$geoIntersects": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": fakeUser.loc
            }
        }
    }
}, function(err, foundGeozone) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('found geozone: ', foundGeozone);
    if (foundGeozone) {
        console.log('found geozone! Good! Save User.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Victor's case, the location field should be 'geoFeature.geometry'

```
Geozone.findOne({ 'geoFeature.geometry':  
    {$geoIntersects:
      {$geometry:{ "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [longitude, latitude] } //fakeUser.loc
      }
    }
})
```